# Error with custom UICollectionViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to setup an `UICollectionView`. At first I was using the basic `UICollectionViewCell`, it was working well, the cells were being displayed.

Then I created my own collectionViewCell (subclassing `UICollectionViewCell`), to be able to display an image in the cell. 
I linked the custom cell in the Storyboard with an identifier and I also specified the right class for it.

However, I keep having this error, and I don't understand why:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier MediaCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

I managed to take care of the bug by adding this line in the `viewDidLoad` but in the tutorials I was following the guys were not using it:

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[MediaCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MediaCell"];
```

The problem is that if I add it, the collectionView remains black and no data is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was actually a problem related with the TabBarController. I wasn't displaying the right class inside it that's why the collectionView was always empty. 
The code I posted here was working. Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 6):

I had this exact issue yesterday (as the documentation says you MUST register the class), but the documentation is inaccurate in that you should not register if a prototype cell exists in your storyboard and you give it an identifier.

If you create a prototype of the `UICollectionViewCell` in your storyboard and assign your custom cell class, it is not necessary (and is detrimental if you do) register the custom `UICollectionViewCell`.  This is the reason the resulting `UICollectionView` is black.

Based on the error message, the prototype cell in the storyboard does not have its identifier set correctly (either not set at all or is not `MediaCell`)

Comment: I assigned the custom cell class in the storyboard and named it MediaCell as well. The curious thing is that the prototype cell in the storyboard does actually have the identifier set, that's why I don't understand the error. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much for this... killed 2 hrs trying to figure out why it wasn't picking up my prototype.

Answer (score 2):

You're right in using the line

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[MediaCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MediaCell"];
```

as this helps with cell reuse.

The problem could be your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, or your subclass, or the way you set up your delegates. Can you post the code?

Your delegate method should look something like this:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MediaCollectionViewCell* cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MediaCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    // set cell.image
    return cell;
}
```

You should set up your delegate in your viewDidLoad method with...

```
[self.collectionView setDataSource:self];
[self.collectionView setDelegate:self];
```

EDIT: 
Can you post the code for your MediaCollectionViewCell implementation? I did something similar, and mine looks like this.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.imageView];
}
return self;
```

}

Comment: I setup the delegate and the datasource in the storyboard. Here is the code for the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` `- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    
    MediaCollectionViewCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MediaCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        
    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[[self.mediaModel.response objectForKey:@"list"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"smallImgUrl"]];

    [[cell imageView]setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]];

    return cell;
    
}`

Comment: The code for the custom cell: `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MediaCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;


@end`      Thanks!

Comment: After getting NSURL *imageURL, where do you use that? It seems like you just set the cell to Default.png, and then return the cell. Are you using imageURL in any way? You would need to download the UIImage from imageURL, and then set that as the image for the cell's imageView.

Comment: I actually used the Default.png just to check that the problem wasn't related to the image download. I think the problem I'm facing is because I'm using a TabBarController that I didn't setup properly.

Comment: See my edited post regarding the initWithFrame method in your MediaCollectionViewCell.m